# How to over ride frontend-blank _navigation.less in custom theme?

Tags: magento2, less-css, less-import

There are a number of great answers on less extending and overriding but none seem to answer this.

I want to override the following in a custom theme.
`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less`

I've tried the following:

1. Copy `_navigation.less` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/custom-theme/web/css/source/_navigation.less` and recompile.
2. Copy `_navigation.less` and `_sources.less` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/custom-theme/web/css/source/` and comment out other partials I don't want to override.
3. Save `theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less` to  `app/design/frontend/Vendor/custom-theme/web/css/source/_navigation_override.less` and import it in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/custom-theme/web/css/_styles.less`

   ```
   @import 'source/_navigation_override.less';
   ```

Option 3 does work but only because it's loaded after _navigation.less so it's not ideal.

Does any know how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Having tested further I can confirm that option 1 above is the correct way to override a less partial from magento blank theme e.g. `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less`.

Copy `_navigation.less` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/custom-theme/web/css/source/_navigation.less` and recompile, but make sure you clear `var/view_preprocessed`as well.

It appeared not to work because `_navigation.less` was being compiled to the pub directory for both `en_US` and `en_GB` and it also is also cached in `var/view_preprocessed....en_GB` so unless you clear all these when you make changes in your theme it will appear not to be being overwritten.